# Jetty webapp: How to restrict access to /admin to internal IPs?

Tags: security, url, jersey, embedded-jetty

We have a web app deployed using embedded Jetty 8.1.10 and Jersey 1.17.1. Now we are required to only allow internal IP addresses to access /admin section, i.e. URLs with /admin segment.

What is the best way to do this with Jetty/Jersey configuration?

Thanks,

Alec

Comment: Do you have a `WEB-INF/web.xml` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way to achieve it is to implement a standard servlet filter (javax.servlet.Filter) and register it in your web.xml

In the doFilter method you get an object representing the request from which you can obtain source IP and path information.

```java
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    HttpServletRequest httpRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
    String ipAddress = httpRequest.getRemoteAddr();
    String path = httpRequest.getPathInfo();

    // do the filtering based on ipAddress and path

    // pass the request along the filter chain
    chain.doFilter(request, response);
}
```

Comment: This is SIMPLEST way?! ... there is no chance to use the jetty's Limit clause somehow?

Comment: @Rafael Maybe not simplest but for sure flexible and universal to every servlet container. If you know a shorter solution specific to Jetty please post the answer.

Comment: Sorry i was only wondering because i expected something more simple. I know there is Limit directive in jetty configuration that's similar to allow, deny on Apache ... this way you may be able to limit from where you are receiving requests. I cannot say for sure because i am searching for the same answer but in my case for embedded server through CXF.